# What's the correct way of putting these objects together to form a game-ready asset?

Tags: mesh, armature, parent, .fbx

I am making a character that will be exported as an .fbx file to a game engine (UE4). I made the basic shape of it using multiple cubes with subsurface modifiers and a mirror modifier for the arms and legs. So I came up with the following result:
[image]

[image]

My very simple collection of cubes looks like this:
[image]

Now I need to:

- Paint this character's textures (which includes UV mapping)
- Rig it
- Create an animation

before doing so am I supposed to join the meshes? If so then do I use a Boolean or CTRL+j? If not then do I parent every object to an armature? Please tell me what's the correct workflow for a game ready character. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would most likely want to have all of these objects joined into the same mesh. You wouldn't use booleans for this. You need to unwrap, and texture, then rig and animate.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What method do you recommend for joining the objects in one mesh?

Comment: Ctrl J as you guessed. It's the only way to "join" mesh, it's even the function's name ;) Also, don't forget to give appropriate names to your objects.

Comment: Some people suggested me to use a Boolean modifier to join the objects because it gets rid of internal geometry. Why would I go for CTRL+J instead of using a Boolean? I would appreciate if you could elaborate on this.

Comment: You could try, but considering the density of the mesh that might make it more likely to create artifacts and weird triangles that you have to edit later anyway. i heard Blender's new Boolean capabilities are great, but I'm not sure if they're that good. What you should do instead is, before you join the meshes, grab the very end of of whichever part actually intersects another part, turn on proportional editing by pressing O, and drag it around inside the other mesh until most of the object is outside of the other one.

Comment: If you already joined the objects, you can edit the proportional falloff option to only affect connected parts. I think that's better than boolean in this instance:
http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html